# How to show date range by using UIDatePicker in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIDatePicker sheet used in my project. It naturally shows one day per date. Actually I wanna see the that day and 9 days after that day. How can I do it?

For example,

```
____________ 
July 13 2015 (Today)
July 14 2015
July 15 2015
____________
July 16 2015
July 17 2015
July 18 2015
July 19 2015
July 20 2015
July 21 2015
```

Only 9 days from today.

Comment: Did you even read `UIDatePicker` documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIDatePicker` has two properties - `minimumDate, maximumDate: NSDate?`

they are nil by default, but you can set them like this:

```
let currentDate: NSDate = NSDate()
let calendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
components.calendar = calendar
components.day = 9

let maxDate: NSDate = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: currentDate, options: nil)!

self.myDatePicker.minimumDate = currentDate
self.myDatePicker.maximumDate = maxDate
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't put a comment onto Adam's answer.
For the line,

```
let maxDate: NSDate = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: currentDate, options: nil)!
```

the options argument no longer takes `nil`. However, you can type `.` to pick one you want. For example: `.MatchFirst`